# Undeclared variable error when using a LIMIT variable with PREPARE in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, limit, prepared-statement

I'm writing a stored procedure. I am having some problems using a variable in combination with LIMIT and a prepared statement. (See code below)

The procedure is created normally, but when I call it I get an error that variable `a` is undeclared. Any suggestions?

```
delimiter //
drop procedure if exists shop1;
create procedure shop1()
begin 
    declare a varchar(255) default null;
    declare counter int(4) default 0;
    declare row_numbers int(4); 
    declare s varchar(255) default null;

    select count(*) into row_numbers from salesmen;
    WHILE counter< row_numbers+1 DO
        set @s='select fio from salesmen into a Limit ? 1';
        set @counter=counter;
        prepare stmt from @s;
        execute stmt using @counter;

        SET counter=counter+1;
        insert into warehouse.place (shop, fio) values (1, a);
    END WHILE;

    SET counter=0;
    select count(*) into row_numbers from products;
    WHILE counter< row_numbers+1 DO
        SET counter=counter+1;
    END WHILE;
end; 
//
```

Comment: ',' didn't helped. The mistake is the same.

Comment: I think, that ',' even is not necessary.

Comment: There is no need to do this by running multiple queries inside a loop. Use a cursor instead - [RefMan](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cursors.html)

Comment: .The problem is solved. I made a user variable `@a=a` and used it in query. Also query must be like this: `set @s='select fio from salesmen Limit ?,1 into @a';`

Comment: @nnichols - A cursor is a loop. So no improvement there. Your other suggestion ie `INSERT .. SELECT ..` makes more sense ;)

Comment: @Leigh - but a loop over the resultset of a single query. If the functionality is as simple as suggested here OP should be using INSERT...SELECT anyway.

Comment: @nnichols - Actually, I think we are in complete agreement. I meant there is little difference between a cursor and a loop. Both are inefficient, and unnecessary. Your second suggestion of using a single statement ie `INSERT...SELECT` is a much better way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an INSERT ... SELECT to do the same thing -

```
INSERT INTO warehouse.place (shop, fio)
SELECT 1, fio FROM salesmen
```

Comment: Much more efficient than looping with `LIMIT`

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean?

```
set @s='select fio from salesmen into a Limit ?,1';
```